# URLs to images get messed up after migration

Tags: migration

I migrated a website from one host to another, and I am having a weird issue I never encountered before. The urls to images in html are fine, but the full path to the image has a broken url, the domain outputs twice.

So here is the code generated for an image:

`<img src="subdomain.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/aleksandra.jpg" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="aleksandra">`

And here is the full path to the image in inspector:

`http://subdomain.domain.com/subdomain.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/aleksandra.jpg`

If you need more info please do not hesitate to ask. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In all cases like this happen? the urls of the images in the wp_posts.post_content field in the database. How are they?

Comment: This is probably (but not sure) due to some theme / plugin that do not use the right function to get the URL.I assume that now it takes the ABSOLUTE server path, which I can assume on your new server is a PARKED domain or ADDON, as opposed to what you had before . try to see if it happens also with internal links. also try `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'subdomain.domain.com/subdomain.domain.com', 'subdomain.domain.com');` and `UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://subdomain.domain.com/subdomain.domain.com','http://subdomain.domain.com');` in Mysql to see

Comment: in the database links are ok

Comment: i did a database search for 'subdomain.domain.com/subdomain.domain.com' and there were no results, i deactivated all the plugins

Comment: @BojanaŠekeljić that mean you maybe did not put the correct URL while migrating . ( maybe forgot the `http://` or maybe left the main domain in the `home url` or `blog url` options)

Comment: yeah i figured it out, that's exactly what happened... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, when I was exporting the database using Migrate DB plugin, I didn't put the `http://` before the new domain... so all the internal links were broken.

Answer (score 1):

Back up your database (this is very very important) and download and install "Velvet Blues Update URLs" plugin.  On the settings page enter in the old URL field http://subdomain.domain.com/subdomain.domain.com

Enter in the new URL field the URL of your website. Select all options and click "Update". Update your permalinks as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [plugin like WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) which enables you to enter the new site address and server path before exporting the database. This does a search find and replace which you may need to do now using a solution like https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

"Velvet Blues Update URLs" plugin is another solution or export your DB again.

Comment: Yeah I used WP Migrate DB, but made a mistake, didn't add http:// for new url. Thanks for the answer!