# Update all images url imported from HTML pages

Tags: posts, images, uploads, import

I have to copy content from different website. I copied whole webpage and paste it in my post. All works fine. I also get images in my post but they are still linked to older website.

Is there any plugin or way so that I will check for all such image URL called from other website? Plugin could copy upload files and then show from our website instead showing it from old one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLs to images get messed up after migration](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133574/urls-to-images-get-messed-up-after-migration)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a plugin!
Wordpress stores uploaded images in a media library which puts them in the posts table.
As you have copied and pasted they are not in the media library, but just as img tags in the posts/pages themselves.

Step 1 - copy the image files themselves, using an FTP to download them all then put them in newdomainname.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04 - ie this months upload folder!
Step 2 You can log into PHPMyAdmin to quickly update all the images in the posts/pages. Change the urls ;-)

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'src="http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

That won't have put the images in the media library for making thumbnails, feature images etc, but it will have moved them over.

You can then use https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/ to add the uploaded images into the library.