# Images Wont Display After Importing From Old Wordpress

Tags: images

The images in my posts are not displaying, but when I click them, they display perfectly fine.  It seems like the issue is the actual image is: `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/holding-baby.jpg` but in the posts i have something like `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/holding-baby-248x450.jpg`

The image with the file size didnt get copied over but the real image did.  Is there anything I can do to mass fix this? What are my options

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks

Comment: @PieterGoosen how do i do that?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I tried regenerating thumbnails but with no luck.. not sure about flushing permalinks though

Comment: Just visit the permalinks setting page in the back end

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have it set to "post name"

Comment: what @PieterGoosen said and make sure to save them even if they are set.

Comment: [This might help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/133574/31545)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress generate some smaller images (the thumbnails) so, the images are on your server, but thumbnails are not. If the issue is just a thumbnail rebuild, you can do rebuild them with this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/

With lucky you will not need to do anything else. But thumbnails sizes are defined per theme, plugin or even in WordPress settings, and they are not permanent. If today your setting is defined to 250px x 250px, all your images uploaded today will create a thumbnail of that size, then if tomorrow you change to 300px x 300px, then your new image size will be this one.

In the end, there is a high chance of you need to go post by post editing the images and inserting the new one. But let's hope that a simple rebuild will work!

Ps.: You can also upload your old wp-content/uploads folder to the new server, is the only way to have the same content.

Comment: this worked for some posts but not all of them

Comment: Yes, I thought that this would happen. You probably had different sizes settings for different moments, so this will happen. Unfortunately I don't know any plugin which can fix this programatically, I fear that you will need to do it manually.